# Нужна ли запятая в предложениях с "из-за"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, спп

Нужна ли запятая в предложении по такой модели: "Из-за того, что было сделано одно(,) им пришлось делать другое"?

Или: "Из-за неисправности двух компонентов(,) отказал и третий".

Или: "Из-за неисправности двух компонентов(,) им пришлось отключить систему целиком".

Или: "Он не знал(,) из-за чего система перестала работать".

Благодарю!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запятая ставится в 1-м и 4-м предложениях, которые в своём составе имеют две основы:

*Из-за того, что **было сделано одно**, им **пришлось делать** другое.

**Он не знал**, из-за чего **система перестала работать***.

2-е и 3-е предложения не требуют постановки запятой (одна основа):

*Из-за неисправности двух компонентов **отказал** и **третий**.

Из-за неисправности двух компонентов им **пришлось отключить** систему целиком.*

Comment: Спасибо большое! Здорово!

Comment: @Arsenii  Спасибо за вопрос и оценку!